# Как осуществить поиск групп символов с определённого места в строке?

Tags: python-3.x, строки, кодировка

Нужна программа (функция), которая будет получать строку вида "некий текст: mmmmmpmmf" и возвращать "некий текст: абв", то есть всё, что содержится до двоеточия, вернётся в первозданном виде, а текст после двоеточия будет переводиться в буквы с помощью заранее известного словаря. При этом заглавные и строчные буквы учитываются, так MMM = A, mmm = a

Вот словарь:

`('mmm', 'а')
('mmp', 'б')
('mmf', 'в')
('mpm', 'г')
('mpp', 'д')
('mpf', 'е')
('mpf', 'ё')
('mfm', 'ж')
('mfp', 'з')
('mff', 'и')
('mff', 'й')
('pmm', 'к')
('pmp', 'л')
('pmf', 'м')
('ppm', 'н')
('ppp', 'о')
('ppf', 'п')
('pfm', 'р')
('pfp', 'с')
('pff', 'т')
('fmm', 'у')
('fmp', 'ф')
('fmf', 'х')
('fpm', 'ц')
('fpm', 'ч')
('fpp', 'ш')
('fpp', 'щ')
('fpf', 'ъ')
('fpf', 'ы')
('fpf', 'ь')
('ffm', 'э')
('ffp', 'ю')
('fff', 'я')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если всегда ключ словаря это три символа, тогда можно так.

```
conv = dict([('mmm', 'а'), ('mmp', 'б'), ('mmf', 'в'), ('mpm', 'г'), 
('mpp', 'д'), ('mpf', 'е'), ('mpf', 'ё'), ('mfm', 'ж'), ('mfp', 'з'),
('mff', 'и'), ('mff', 'й'), ('pmm', 'к'), ('pmp', 'л'), ('pmf', 'м'), 
('ppm', 'н'), ('ppp', 'о'), ('ppf', 'п'), ('pfm', 'р'), ('pfp', 'с'), 
('pff', 'т'), ('fmm', 'у'), ('fmp', 'ф'), ('fmf', 'х'), ('fpm', 'ц'),
('fpm', 'ч'), ('fpp', 'ш'), ('fpp', 'щ'), ('fpf', 'ъ'), ('fpf', 'ы'),
('fpf', 'ь'), ('ffm', 'э'), ('ffp', 'ю'), ('fff', 'я')])

prefix, text = input().split(':')
text = text.strip().split()

new_text = []
for word in text:
    new_word = []
    for i in range(0, len(word), 3):
        key = word[i:i+3]
        value = conv[key.lower()]
        if key.isupper():
            value = value.upper()
        new_word.append(value)
    new_text.append(new_word)


result = ' '.join(''.join(word) for word in new_text)
print('%s: %s' % (prefix, result))
```

Comment: Ваш код работает, но когда дело доходит до разделения слов/букв пробелом, то выдаёт ошибку. Вводные данные: 'mmm mmm'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "путь к файлу", line 15, in <module>
    value = conv[key.lower()]
KeyError: ' mm'

Comment: @SnoopyDoopy ну, тогда вот так.

Comment: Всё работает, но у меня снова возникла небольшая проблема. В этих сообщения возможны эмодзи (UTF-8) в нетронутом виде, как заставить программу переварить их и отправить обратно в том же виде?

Comment: @SnoopyDoopy а эмодзи отделены пробелами?

Comment: Я уже понял, что эмодзи это не основная проблема. А основная проблема это знаки препинания, что намного сложнее реализовать на мой взгляд.

Comment: А так же цифры и английские слова, не содержащие сочетания из словаря, он их трогать не должен.

Comment: Это сильно другой код получается.